# Debugging C code while executing within Python

Tags: python, c, gdb

I have some C codes compiled with -g flag. I control my execution in Python; I launch the executable in python using os, and then do some stuff with output. I have some difficulties with the C code, and need to debug my code. I have tried the `gdb attach`. However, the problem is in some situations the C code terminates very fast before I am able to attach to its process in gdb. Also, when I run with gdb like

```
gdb --args python mycode.py
```

and use `file` command to bring the symobls in. I would get segfault

```
/home/cc/scarab/src/param_parser.c:735: WARNING (P=0  O=0  I=0  C=0):  Parameter file 'PARAMS.in' not found --- Using hard-coded defaults and command-line arguments only.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7121334 in fclose () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Is there any way that I debug with gdb?

Comment: Did you try to instrument your code so that it waits for you to attach?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code before running it. Main is a good place to start.

Comment: This is extremely unclear, show a [example] what exactly you did. -- Can't you just run `gdb` from inside Python itself?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the valgrind to see if there are any memory related issues. Can you please share the complete backtrace/stacktrace. If it is in fclose the file pointer may be invalid.
Attach the program after the gdb is invoked and also do the single stepping to know where exactly is the issue. This looks like some memory related issue. Check all pointers (file ptrs) in the source code.